# Open a div and show the data

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML shown below

```
<div id="activeui5" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
   <div class="prd-items-detials">
      <ul>
         <li class="head">
            <form>
                <i class="icon-Description" descid="5" id="desc5" description="This is Popcorn" alt="Description" title="Description" style="display:block">
               </i>
               <i class="delete-item-btn"></i>
            </form>
         </li>
         <li class="prd-items-qt">
            <div style="display:none" class="description-details"></div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a requirement as when clicked on the **icon-Description** class , i need to append the data to another class named **description-details** and display that .

I tried this way , but its not showing up anything

```
 $(document).on("click", ".icon-Description", function() {
  var desc = $(this).attr("description");
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).find(".prd-items-qt").find('.description-details').empty();
  $(this).find(".prd-items-qt").find('.description-details').append(desc);
    $(this).find(".prd-items-qt").find('.description-details').toggle();
});
```

There is no exception under the console . 
Could anybody please help me on this .

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b5Z2v/1/

Comment: can you pls share a jsbin?

Comment: You have a syntax error at the end of the element with the `icon-Description` class

Comment: Whats up with `style="display:block" ;"=""` ?

Comment: I am sorry for the code , this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b5Z2v/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use data attributes, `data-description` .... and to change your code to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".icon-Description", function() {
    var desc = $(this).data("description");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var dest = $(this).closest('ul').find(".prd-items-qt").find('.description-details');
    dest.html( desc ).toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/b5Z2v/2/)

**NOTE**

Since, `.prd-items-qt` is not a descendant of `.icon-Description`, you have to go up to an element that is an ancestor of `.prd-items-qt` -- `ul` -- using `.closest()`. Then you can use `.find()` to locate `.prd-items-qt` and `.description-details`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code

JS

```
        $(document).on("click", ".icon-Description", function() {
        var desc = $(this).attr("description");
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var nxt_li_details = $(this).parents('li').next('li').find('.description-details');
       nxt_li_details.empty();
      nxt_li_details.html(desc);
        nxt_li_details.toggle();
    });
```

The selector for next `.description-details` was incorrect. Used a variable `nxt_li_details` to make it more easier to understand. 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/g6T9Y/)